# Use my custom user in asp mvc 5 application

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I want use my own User rather than using the ApplicationUser provided by the .Net framework.

In my Register method i have :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }
```

Is there any way to use a custom user class instead of using the default user application even if I know that we can add some properties for the default UserAplication.

some thing like :

```
var user = new MyUser() { UserName = model.UserName, LastName = "LastName "};
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try searching for a CustomMembershipProvider?

Comment: @derape the question about Asp.Net Identity which supersedes membership providers. Membership providers no more.

Comment: @derape , i did, but i just find how can i costume ApplicationUser(), not how can i replace it by my own user class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the prettiest of solutions, but..

Remove the ApplicationUser class from the MVC project, compile. Where you get compile errors, replace the reference to the ApplicationUser class with your MyUser class.

And remember, MyUser has to inherit from the IdentityUser class.

Comment: Thank's for responding